# Mapping SQL Server numeric(1,0) type to bool

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How do I write the mapping from a SQL Servre column of type `numeric (1,0)` to a `bool` parameter in the class??

```
Property(t => t.boolparameter).HasColumnName("intparameter").HasColumnType("numeric");
```

and I get an error here..

Comment: ***W-H-A-T*** error did you get?? Don't just tease us - and remember: we **cannot** see neither your screen, nor can we read your mind - **you'll have to TELL US!**

Comment: @marc_s The error is that you can't map int to boolean type, because the returned value from DB is 1(int32) and the type of object to which I try to assign this 1(it can only be 1 or 0) is bool. So the error is that int32!= bool